Machine precision in ReplaceRepeated
I am relatively new in Mathematica and facing the following issue. I replace the parameters in an expression with a list of values using the function ReplaceRepeated and am getting the error: General::munfl: Exp[-4500.000000000001`] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost. Please see the first part of the code below. By searching potential solutions to this problem, I found out that setting the max precision can fix the issue. Indeed, it does. Please see the second part of the code below. However, I am unsure how to set up the max precision during the execution of the function ReplaceRepeated. I have tried multiple ways and none of them have fixed the problem. While I keep searching for a solution, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix it.
params = {
   f -> 2.516460605224352,
   \[Omega]0 -> 2 \[Pi]*f,
   \[Sigma] -> 60*10^-1};

ReplaceRepeated[#, params] &@(E^(-(1/2) \[Sigma]^2 \[Omega]0^2))
`General::munfl: Exp[-4500.000000000001`] is too small to represent as a normalized \
machine number; precision may be lost`

N[Exp[-4500], 100]

4.72967648311064156740578325969642440169791394137631932895049535614722\
0919012810780076139344249084318*10^-1955



I'm not entirely sure what you think the problem is or what you expect to see as the result, but you can set the precision of the number in params to 100 digits like this: 2.516460605224352`100.

You are using a machine precision decimal for f which limits your calculation to machine precision.  Use an exact number for f or higher precision such as f->2.516460605224352\100`

Since that particular number is the only finite-precision number, Mathematica will try to maintain that degree of precision. If there were other finite-precision numbers, the lowest precision input would be the constraint on the output precision.

The message is warning you about floating-point underflow. It's not an error unless you wish to treat it as one. If you wish to treat it as an error, you need to define how to handle. (Or you could use arbitrary-precision numbers, the alternative suggested by others, if you think that's the right way to set up your problem.)

Understood. Thank you.

Do I need to set manually the precision of each single parameters involved in the notebook? Is there a way to set it up for all the parameters in the notebook?
